# webView loadHTMLString completion?

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, ios6

There are a few question about this, which has a solution regarding the script embedded in html string. Not in my case.

I have a ios5/6 app.
I have tryed to put the loading code into `initWithNibName` bad idea, `viewDidLoad` is deprecated , so `viewWillAppear` left.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSString* detailHtml = [Storage getDetailHtml: -1];// get the last one
    //NSLog(@"detailHtml: %@", detailHtml);
    if(detailHtml == nil){
        NSLog(@"Can't load the detail");
        detailHtml = @"<html><body>Some text here</body></html>";
    }   
    [webView loadHTMLString:detailHtml baseURL:nil];


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

The problem with this code is flashing. It appears the UIViewContoller, with a white webView than after 1-2 seconds it is displayed the html. The HTML has some texts, but has base64 encoded images too, sometimes it is around 3Mb even 5MB content. No javascript is here, just inline CSS ( no external file ), text and base 64 encoded images.

I could pre-load into `detailHtml` the text, but I think the displaying takes more time.

Is that possible to do not display the ViewController, until the webView hasn't finished loading the html ? -  some callback?

Any suggestions?

Comment: That would take little bit time to load the HTML string.But if everything works fine the why don't you put UIActivityIndicator so that would keep user engaged with the app.Even much better than keeping it blank.

Comment: @AjaySharma and when to stop the indicator? :) just asked for a callback :)

Comment: there is delegate method use this : - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView.And stop your indicator over here.

Comment: @AjaySharma pls add your comments as answer, to be accepted and upvoted!

Comment: Thanks... I liked your favour ;)

Comment: I don't think viewDidLoad is deprecated? Only viewDidUnload/viewWillUnload....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would take little bit time to load the HTML string default.But if everything works fine the why don't you put `UIActivityIndicator` so that would keep user engaged with the app.Even much better than keeping it blank

**Here is one the delegate method of `UIWebView` :**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
//And stop your indicator over here
   [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: if really does't want the user the white thing I hope i can call a callback from the calling UIViewController to this and only than pop it, for now it is ok, thanks

Comment: Yes you are right bro.. but this is in general who don't want his view to be popped up & loading on the same screen, at that time, this delegate method would be really helpful.